# Set difference with XPath 1.0 - how do I get .//table without .//table//table?

Tags: xpath, set-difference

I'm trying to find all the tables **below my current node** without also including the nested tables.  In other words, if I have this, i want to find "yes" and not "no":

```
<table> <!-- outer table - no -->
  <tr><td>
    <div> <!-- *** context node *** -->
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there any easy way to do this in XPath 1.0?  (In 2.0, it'd be `.//table except .//table//table`, but I don't have a 2.0 as an option.)

**EDIT:** please, the answers so far are not respecting the idea of current context node. I don't know how far down the first layer of table might be (and it might differ), and I also don't know if I might be inside another table (or two or three).

Literally, I want what `.//table except .//table//table` in XPath 2.0 would be, but I have only XPath 1.

Comment: I think that it is impossible write only one XPath 1.0 because I need use one context multiple times and it is not allowed. Can I use two XPaths, one XPath for getting value of variable and 2nd XPath for getting required tables?

Comment: You've made this a CW for what reason?  Its quite a tricky question which will have a right answer, its not a candidate for CW.

Comment: What's a "CW"?  And who are you addressing as "you" there? Me? How did I make this a "CW"? :)

Comment: CW is "Community Wiki" - at the most basic level it makes your question a: more editable by other people, and b: you don't gain any rep points from it; but in reality it tends to imply it is a more discussion-based question. You did this by clicking a checkbox, and there is no "undo" - but ultimately if you get a suitable answer this doesn't make a huge amount of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating it here and elsewhere, the answer seems to be "you can't, and that's why we have XPath 2.0".  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want child::table aka table

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
{
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();

  $tree->parse(<<'__HTML__');
<table> <!-- outer table - no -->
  <tr><td>
    <div> <!-- *** context node *** -->
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
__HTML__

  sub HTML::Element::addressx {
    return join(
      '/',
      '/', # // ROOT
      reverse(    # so it starts at the top
        map {
          my $n = $_->pindex() || '0';
          my $t = $_->tag;
          $t . '['. $n .']'
          }         # so that root's undef -> '0'
          $_[0],    # self and...
        $_[0]->lineage
      )
    );
  } ## end sub HTML::Element::addressx

  for my $td ( $tree->look_down( _tag => qr/div|table/i ) ) {
    print $td->addressx, "\n";
  }
  $tree->delete;
  undef $tree;
}
__END__
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]/table[0]
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/table[0]
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]/table[1]
//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]/table[1]/tr[0]/td[0]/table[0]
```

and second part

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_content(<<'__HTML__');
<table> <!-- outer table - no -->
  <tr><td>
    <div> <!-- *** context node *** -->
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
      <table> <!-- yes -->
        <tr><td>
          <table> ... </table> <!-- no -->
        </td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </td></tr>
</table>
__HTML__



#~ for my $result ($tree->findnodes(q{//html[0]/body[1]/table[0]/tr[0]/td[0]/div[0]})) {
for my $result ($tree->findnodes(q{/html/body/table/tr/td/div})) {
    print $result->as_HTML,"\n\n";
    for my $table( $result->findnodes(q{table}) ){ ## child::table
        print "$table\n";
        print $table->as_HTML,"\n\n\n";
    }

}

__END__
<div><table><tr><td><table><tr><td> ... </td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><table><tr><td> ... </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>


HTML::Element=HASH(0xc6c964)
<table><tr><td><table><tr><td> ... </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>



HTML::Element=HASH(0xc6cbf4)
<table><tr><td><table><tr><td> ... </td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Nope, not respecting the context node.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand it, the content_list can solve:

```
my $table_one = $tree->findnodes('/html//table')->[1];

for ( $table_one->content_list ) {
    last if $_->exists('table');
    print $_->as_text;
}
```

:)

Comment: Nope.  That doesn't respect the context node.

Answer (score 0):

What about `.//table[not(.//table)]`? Sorry for brevity, I'm on my phone.

Comment: Nope, that finds all tables that don't have tables in them.  I want all tables that are not within tables.

Comment: OK, how about .//table[not(ancestor::table)] ?  That's quite likely to be inefficient though, unless you're doing it in something like eXist, which has the indexes to support it.

Comment: Nope.  That finds all tables as long as they're not within *any* table.  But consider what happens if our context node is already within a table.  It'd find *nothing*.  Nope, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't know how to get the context node to be evaluated in the nested predicates, but what you need is something like this:</strike>

```
descendant::table[not(ancestor::table[ancestor::div])]
```

only with the ability to reference the context node, instead of `div`

**EDIT**: If you set a variable for the context node,

```
<xsl:variable name="contextNode" select="." />
```

then you can reference it in the XPATH predicate:

```
descendant::table[not(ancestor::table[ancestor::*[generate-id(.)=generate-id($contextNode)]])]
```

Comment: Yeah, that still won't work, since it'll rule out any tables that are within any table that are within any div. :)  Not respecting the context again.

Comment: Updated my answer.  It's not pure XPATH, but is an XPATH 1.0 (and XSLT 1.0) solution.

Comment: Yeah, no XSLT here.  So that doesn't do it either.  {Sigh}.